# Dando erro na hora de validar os dados vindo do formulário

Tags: php

O erro é

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\sessao\cadastro.php on line 61
```

Não sei o que faço. Alguém sabe resolver?

```
include ("conexao_sessao.php");

// verifica se os campos foram preenchidos&& iss
if ( isset($_POST['nome']) && isset($_POST['sobrenome']) &&  isset($_POST['genero']) && isset($_POST['dia']) && isset($_POST['mes']) && isset($_POST['ano']) && isset($_POST['instituicao_tec']) && isset($_POST['tecnico']) && isset($_POST['instituicao_tec2']) && isset($_POST['tecnico2']) && isset($_POST['instituicao_acad']) && isset($_POST['graduacao']) && ($_POST['especialidade']) && isset($_POST['instituicao_acad2']) && isset($_POST['graduacao2']) && ($_POST['especialidade2']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['senha']) && isset($_POST['conf_senha'])){
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$sobrenome = $_POST['sobrenome'];
$genero = $_POST['genero'];
$dia = $_POST['dia'];
$mes = $_POST['mes'];
$ano = $_POST['ano'];
$instituicao_tec = $_POST['instituicao_tec'];
$instituicao_tec2 = $_POST['instituicao_tec2'];
$tecnico = $_POST['tecnico'];
$tecnico2 = $_POST['tecnico2'];
$instituicao_acad = $_POST['instituicao_acad'];
$instituicao_acad2 = $_POST['instituicao_acad2'];
$graduacao = $_POST['graduacao'];  
$graduacao2 = $_POST['graduacao2'];
$especialidade = $_POST['especialidade'];
$especialidade2 = $_POST['especialidade2']; 
$email = $_POST['email'];
$senha = $_POST['senha'];
$conf_senha = $_POST['conf_senha'];


//verifica se o campo senha e igual ao campo confime a senha


if($nome == ""){
    echo '<script>alert("Preencha o campo nome!");</script>';
}elseif($sobrenome == ""){
    echo '<script>alert("Peencha o campo Sobrenome!");</script>';   
}elseif($genero == ""){
    echo  '<script>alert("Escolha o Genero!");</script>';
}elseif($dia == "" && $mes == "" && $ano == ""){
    echo '<script>alert("Escolha a data de nascimento!");</script>';
}elseif($senha != $conf_senha){
    echo '<script>alert("Digite as senhas corretamente!");</script>';
}else{
$validaremail = mysql_query("SELECT*FROM usuarios WHERE email = '$email'");
$contar = mysql_num_rows($validaremail);
if($contar == 0){
$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `usuarios`( `nome`, `sobrenome`, `genero`, `dia`, `mes`, `ano`, `instituicao_tec`, `tecnico`, `instituicao_tec2`, `tecnico2`, `instituicao_acad`,  `graduacao`, `especialidade`, `instituicao_acad2`,  `graduacao2`, `especialidade2`, `email`, `senha`) VALUES('$nome','$sobrenome', '$genero', '$dia', '$mes', '$ano', '$instituicao_tec', '$tecnico', '$instituicao_tec2', '$tecnico2','$instituicao_acad', '$graduacao', '$especialidade','$instituicao_acad2', '$graduacao2', '$especialidade2' , '$email','$senha')") or die(mysql_error());
    }else{
        echo '<script>alert("Desculpe, mas já existe um usuário cadastrado com este e-mail em nosso sistema!");</script>';
    }if(isset($insert)){
        echo '<script>alert(" Cadastro realizado com sucesso!");</script>';
    }else{  
        echo '<script>alert("Ops. Houve algum erro no nosso sistema");</script>';
    }   
}   


?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Na última linha do código, adicione uma chave de fechamento

```
}
```

Mais um detalhe, não relacionado com o problema em si, na condicional principal onde verifica o `$_POST` com `isset()`:

`&& ($_POST['especialidade'])` e `&& ($_POST['especialidade2'])`

Não faltou especificar `isset()`?

`&& isset($_POST['especialidade2'])`

Outros assuntos como segurança, padrões de código, conceitos, etc, me abstenho a comentar pois apenas complicaria o assunto.

Todavia, procure pelo menos saber sobre padrões de código: http://www.php-fig.org/psr/

Comment: Valeu, agradece. Erro besta, sou iniciante.

Comment: Acredito que tenha muitos erros, mas esse é o primeiro formulário que estou construindo. Estou usando outros códigos como base. Minha intenção é construir uma rede social.